# navigator.clipboard.readText() is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have this code for paste:

```js
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(
  clipText => document.querySelector("#Note").innerText += clipText);
```

But It has this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: navigator.clipboard.readText is not a function

***help me to solve this bug***

Comment: Works fine when I test it, must be something other in your code causing this.

Comment: It didn't work when I tested it in Stackoverflow

Comment: I did it in codepen, it definitely works. You have to ensure you're focused on the document .e.g. the white page.

Comment: I tested it with console.log but it didn't work

Comment: use this to detect support in your browser, `typeof navigator.clipboard.readText !== "undefined"`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm guessing you are testing it in Firefox, in that case:

> Firefox only supports reading the clipboard in browser extensions, using the "clipboardRead" extension permission.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText#browser_compatibility

Comment: Although this prevents me from doing what I wanted, I'm glad that Firefox chose to behave this way.

Answer (score 24):

Reading clipboard on Firefox (version 94, nov 2021) doesn't seem to work and throws an error:

```
var promise = navigator.clipboard.readText();

// Uncaught TypeError: navigator.clipboard.readText is not a function
```

Documentation on MDN Web Docs suggests to grant permission via Permission API:

> The "clipboard-read" permission of the Permissions API must be granted
> before you can read data from the clipboard.

But `clipboard-read` doesnt seem to be supported:

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: "clipboard-read" });

// Uncaught TypeError: 'clipboard-read' is not a valid value for enumeration PermissionName.
```

The only way to enable clipboard reading (and writing) is to enable `dom.events.testing.asyncClipboard` on Firefox client:

1. Enter `about:config` in navigation bar
2. Click "Accept the Risk and Continue"
3. Search `dom.events.testing.asyncClipboard` and set `true`

Comment: How can you test this needs to be done and advise the user?

Comment: I also had to set `dom.events.asyncClipboard.readText` to true in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Even though `navigator.clipboard.readText()` is not supported in Firefox, I feel compelled to point out that you CAN copy something to the clipboard with Firefox using a different approach that doesn't require it being expressly enabled:

```js
const copy = document.getElementById('copy');
const copy2 = document.getElementById('copy2');
const copyIt = document.getElementById('copyIt');

const copyToClipboard = (str) => {
  if (navigator 
      && navigator.clipboard 
      && navigator.clipboard.writeText)
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(str);
    return Promise.reject("The Clipboard API is not available.");
};

copyIt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  copyToClipboard(copy.value);
  copy2.focus();
  copyIt.innerText = "Now right-click & paste into textarea above.";
});
```

```html
  <textarea name="copy" id="copy" cols="30" rows="10" style="width:90vw;height:25px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad quos, quae a dicta. Quibusdam autem debitis beatae laboriosam nemo illo aliquid. Itaque, doloremque, dicta. Culpa officiis illo cum quisquam rem.</textarea>
<textarea name="copy2" id="copy2" cols="30" rows="10" style="width:90vw;height:25px;"></textarea>
<br><button id="copyIt">Copy It</button>
```

I just wanted anyone that was having the same issues with Firefox as the OP to know that it *was* possible to do...

Comment: The question was about _reading_ the clipboard content, which doesn't work in firefox, while your example describes _writing content to_ the clipboard, which _does_ work in firefox. E.g. you can't copy something from elsewhere, and then display that clipboard content on your page. (Thanks for the example anyway.)