# How to get the content from clipboard on Firefox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very frustrated to make Paste from the clipboard on my React app.

I used `navigator.clipboard.readText()`, which works perfectly on Chrome browser.
But it doesn't work on my latest Firefox browser.

I tried to search SO and there are few posts related to it. But all of them don't make me happy.

According to MDN documentation, it says:

> Blockquote Firefox only supports reading the clipboard in browser extensions, using the "clipboardRead" extension permission.

But I really don't know how to enable it.

Could you help me out with this issue?
Is there any good library for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that the New API is only supported in browser extensions as the MDN docs, so your only hope is to use the old synchronous API only on Firefox

Comment: Here is the same problem explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67440036/navigator-clipboard-readtext-is-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=clipboard.read), Firefox only supports reading the clipboard in browser extensions.

This [article's selected answer](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1068472) says that Firefox currently doesn't allow web pages to access the clipboard via JavaScript, so your only option would be to use the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

What I did in one of my projects is to register an eventListener for the document to handle the paste event in a useEffect hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const pasteFn = (event) => {
      const data = event.clipboardData.items;
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        if (data[i].kind === 'string' && data[i].type.match('^text/plain')) {
          data[i].getAsString((str) => console.log('text/plain', str));
        } else if (data[i].kind === 'string' && data[i].type.match('^text/html')) {
          data[i].getAsString((str) => console.log('html', str));
        } else if (data[i].kind === 'string' && data[i].type.match('^text/uri-list')) {
          data[i].getAsString((str) => console.log('uri', str));
        } else if (data[i].kind === 'file' && data[i].type.match('^image/')) {
          const f = data[i].getAsFile();
          console.log('File', f);
        }
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener('paste', pasteFn);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('paste', pasteFn); // clean up
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

`navigator.clipboard` is an API that works only on secure environments. It could be just that you are running your React app on localhost, a non-secure env and it doesn't have access to the clipboard object from the browser.

You could have a check to see if `navigator.clipboard` is available on the environment and then use it.

```
if (navigator.clipboard !== undefined) {
  // make use of clipboard functions here
}
```

Comment: the MDN docs clearly states that the `readText` API is only supported in browser extensions

Comment: @niceman which extension should I install?

Comment: @LikiCrus the MDN docs means that your react app must be the browser extension itself, not that you need to install a browser extension to get access to the API

Comment: Oh, then should I make something?@niceman, is there any opensource I can easily refer to?

Comment: @niceman I don't see such requirement. Doc says what requirements are IF you work on extensions. It does not translates that it is supported only in extensions. "From version 122, Web extensions require the clipboardRead permission in manifest to read data."