# Can a webpage clipboard paste text and image at same time?

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, paste

I have copied an image and text from the Microsoft Word File. And I wanted to paste the  image and text at the same time on the webpage.

I have developed a Javascript code for pasting from the clipboard. But right my code can only consider one thing at a time either text or an image at one time.

I wanted to know whether its possible or not to paste both things (Text and image) at same time on the webpage?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT 20221120 Significant very simple option added]

There at least three ways you can do this.  I will cover two of them here. And I will try to get to the third one later.

The first one requires browser specific code.

In the following code, the clickpaster() works in Chrome on Windows, but not in native Firefox.

By the far the simplest way to do it is to attribute a target area with ' contenteditable="true" '. This works in both Chrome and Firefox, and requires no javascript.  In this case you can intercept the paste event if you wish.  This method is also coded below.

```js
async function clickpaster(event) {
    const contents = await navigator.clipboard.read();
    for ( var item of contents ) {
        if ( item.types.includes('text/html') ) {
            //  mixed media - text and image
            var blob = await item.getType('text/html');
            var text = await blob.text();
            var newPara = document.createElement("p");
            newPara.innerHTML = text;
            document.getElementById("clickpastetarget").appendChild(newPara);
        } else if ( item.types.includes('image/png') ) {
            //  image only
            var blob = await item.getType('image/png');
            var newImage = document.createElement("img");
            newImage.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            document.getElementById("clickpastetarget").appendChild(newImage);
        } else if ( item.types.includes('text/plain') ) {
            //  text only
            var blob = await item.getType('text/plain');
            var text = await blob.text();
            var newPara = document.createElement("p");
            newPara.innerHTML = text;
            document.getElementById("clickpastetarget").appendChild(newPara);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#clickpastetarget {
    padding: 25px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: wheat;
}

#contextpastetarget {
    padding: 25px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickpastetarget" onclick="clickpaster(event)">Click to paste here.</div>
<div id="contextpastetarget" contenteditable="true">Context click menu, or ctrl-v, to paste here.</div>
```

For the clickpaste()  option, you will need to add 'URL.revokeObjectURL()', etc at some point to release resources. It does not work in native Firefox.  This is a general clipboard API issue, not for only mixed media.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73613086/how-to-get-the-content-from-clipboard-on-firefox-in-javascript) for how you might get it to work in Firefox.

Note that you may have permission/security protocol problems.  For example, the above may not run, or not run fully, especially for images, inside SOs iframe fiddler for that reason.  The code does run locally in trusted contexts though.