# Pasting an image and a text from the clipboard at same time on a website

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I wanted to know if it is possible to paste an image and a text at the same time. I have developed a JavaScript code which can copy text, images and can paste it on a webpage.

But the issue is that it it is considering only one thing at a time, either an image or a text while pasting. It's not pasting both.

I wanted to know that whether is it possible to perform this on javascript?. If yes then what should I do to make this task possible.?

Comment: because the variable is getting overwritten try storing image & text in separate variables and appending both when pasting

Answer (score 0):

If you have text or images or text and images in the clipboard, for example resulting from a copy to clipboard, then the simplest way to paste the entire contents into a DOM element, is to make that element able to be edited, for example:

CSS

```
#contextpastetarget {
    padding: 25px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="contextpastetarget" contenteditable="true">Context click menu, or ctrl-v, to paste here.</div>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73898411/can-a-webpage-clipboard-paste-text-and-image-at-same-time/74500551#74500551) for more information.