# How do I read the clipboard with blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, clipboard, clipboard.js

I am using a Blazor Server application that have a screencasting feature. My goal is to get the data from clipboard and I am talking about not only a text which is easy but overall some img, files, texts etc.

I have a service named `ClipboardService` and it using `Microsoft.JSInterop`, I know for a fact that you can do something like this to get a text

```cs
public ValueTask<string> ReadTextAsync() {
    return _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("navigator.clipboard.readText");
}
```

and you can use something like `navigator.clipboard.read` but it returns I suppose an empty array for my case. Tried to copy an image and sent it to viewer from blazor app and it just doesn't work how I expect it to work.

Clipboard service:

```cs
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

public sealed class ClipboardService
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

    public ClipboardService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }

    public ValueTask<string> ReadTextAsync()
    {
        return _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("navigator.clipboard.readText");
    }

    public ValueTask WriteTextAsync(string text)
    {
        return _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("navigator.clipboard.writeText", text);
    }
}
```

Does anyone faced something familiar?

Comment: And the last step to make is to enable this thing in the browser, here is the solution for Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67440036/navigator-clipboard-readtext-is-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 3):

**For managing textual** content via `Clipboard API` you should use [readText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText) / [writeText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText), but **for images** it should be [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read) / [write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write).

For **for textual content** you can use the service like in [Gérald Barré example](https://www.meziantou.net/copying-text-to-clipboard-in-a-blazor-application.htm):

```
@page "/"
@inject ClipboardService ClipboardService

<h1>Demo Clipboard!</h1>

<button @onclick="ReadFromClipboard">Read from clipboard</button>
<button @onclick="CopyToClipboard">Copy to clipboard</button>
@text

@code {
    string text;

    async Task ReadFromClipboard()
    {
        // Reading from the clipboard may be denied, so you must handle the exception
        try
        {
            text = await ClipboardService.ReadTextAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot read from clipboard");
        }
    }

    async Task CopyToClipboard()
    {
        // Writing to the clipboard may be denied, so you must handle the exception
        try
        {
            await ClipboardService.WriteTextAsync("https://www.meziantou.net");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot write text to clipboard");
        }
    }
}
```

You can **handle read/write operations for images** similar way - e.g. via `DOM` [canvas.toBlob](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-canvas-toblob). As a starting point, see [post by Christian Liebel](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/pwa/making-of-paint-js-copy-paste/) how to interact with `Clipboard API` to copy and paste images to/from clipboard.

Additional Links:

- For mixed content I would recommend to have a closer look at how to handle `ClipboardItem` in [this](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/#handling-multiple-mime-types) post: [Unblocking clipboard access](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/#handling-multiple-mime-types) by Jason Miller and Thomas Steiner
- Read nice overview of APIs - [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) and deprecated [Document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) - for interacting with the clipboard in [Copy to Clipboard in Blazor](https://chrissainty.com/copy-to-clipboard-in-blazor/) post by Chris Sainty.

Comment: alright, but how do you get this sort of js code to a razor page? by adding a function to script section? or how exactly?

Comment: You can write your JS function or object with functions "read" and "write" (instead of one line for readText/writeText) put JS logic for read/write images inside them and then - call functions by name from blazor - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet) and [samples](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/communicating-between-dotnet-and-javascript-in-blazor-with-in-browser-samples) how to do that