# Is it possible to copy and paste an already selected text into an input text using only Blazor?

Tags: javascript, blazor, copy, clipboard, paste

In Blazor Assembly I want to copy and paste the **selected text** into an `inputArea` "A" by clicking the "A" button. By clicking the "B" button, I want to copy and paste the selected text into an `inputArea` "B". Any ideas?

Can it be done only with Blazor CSharp or do I need to resort to JavaScript?

Comment: Blazor's job is HTML generation and tracking.  For direct modification and interaction with the DOM, use Javascript.  You can make a Blazor component to load each script and expose events through `EventCallback`-- then every time you want this functionality, you can just add the component to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option from blazor is using JSInterop to call readText and writeText from the navigator.clipboard object.
BTW you can wrap JSInterop in a service to manage the clipboard.

Check the answer to this similar question:
[How do I read the clipboard with blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75472912/how-do-i-read-the-clipboard-with-blazor)

and the linked [Gérald Barré's example](https://www.meziantou.net/copying-text-to-clipboard-in-a-blazor-application.htm)

Hope this helps